# Where do sensor models come from?

Tags: sensors, probability

i'm new to robotics. I understood why we talk about probabilities and probabilistic robots, but i don't understand where those probabilities come from, how do i go about building a sensor model? Does the robot use the sensor model to then discard any measurement?

Answer (score 3):

Sensor models are useful in a lot of contexts

1. When we *simulate* our system, we want to simulate the noise properties of the sensor in order to get a feeling for the impact of measurement noise on the control signal etc. If the sensor has a certain probability of dropping a measurement, we want to know the impact this has on our closed-loop performance.
2. When we do *control design*, we want to both make sure that we do not amplify noise too much, but we also want to make sure that the feedback loop is robust and has adequate gain and phase margins. A sensor typically has limited bandwidth, i.e., it acts as a lowpass filter on the true signal to be measured. The lowpass filter property introduces phase lag that can be detrimental to the control performance.

You may get a sensor model in many different ways depending on the type of sensor model you're after.

- Statistical models of the noise may, for instance, be built by recording data in a scenario where the correct measurement is known. Consider an accelerometer that does not move at all, this will allow you to gather some data and determine the distribution of the measurement errors.
- Dynamical models of sensors may sometimes be obtained from datasheets, i.e., the datasheet may list a bandwidth property that indicates that the sensor acts like a lowpass filter and can not reliably measure signals that vary faster than the bandwidth. This type of model can also be obtained by comparing measurements with a sensor that is known to be of higher performance. For some sensors, you may know the mechanism with which it works and can model this. A sensor that measures rotational speed may, for instance, work by measuring the time it takes for the sensor to turn 1/n revolutions for some integer n. You will thus typically get good readings for large velocities, but if n is small, get terrible resolution for low velocities. Some sensors + digital converters have a low resolution, in which case you may have to model quantization effects as well. If the sensor requires some data processing, there might be time delays introduced that must be modeled etc.
- Static models of sensors could perhaps also be considered, e.g., including constant offsets or biases that need to be found and compensated for. This procedure is often called calibration. In the accelerometer case, one may need to find the orientation of the (3DOF) accelerometer w.r.t. the field of gravity etc.